# Angular and Ionic : Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this error when I want to receive data from the server with a REST API and display it in an HTML component through a modal. In console if I get the data but in my HTML view not.

providers/musics/musics.ts

```js
const API:string ="https://webapi.bps.go.id/v1/api/domain/type/prov/prov/1300/key/790ab00650e59132961637e651ba47fb/";
@Injectable()
export class MusicsProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello MusicsProvider Provider');
  }
  getMusic(){
    return this.http.get<any[]>(API);
  }
```

home.ts

```js
    public allMusic =[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public loadingController:LoadingController,
    private musicProvider: MusicsProvider) {
    

  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    let allMusicLoadingController = this.loadingController.create({
        content: "getting your songs from server"
    });
    allMusicLoadingController.present();

    this.musicProvider.getMusic()
        .subscribe((musicList) => 

            {
            allMusicLoadingController.dismiss();
            this.allMusic= musicList
        });
  }
```

home.html

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let music of allMusic">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>{{music.domain_name}}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

this is the json service

```js
{"status":"OK","data-availability":"available","data":[{"page":1,"pages":1,"total":34},[{"domain_id":"1100","domain_name":"Aceh","domain_url":"https:\/\/aceh.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"1200","domain_name":"Sumatera Utara","domain_url":"https:\/\/sumut.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"1300","domain_name":"Sumatera Barat","domain_url":"https:\/\/sumbar.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"1400","domain_name":"Riau","domain_url":"https:\/\/riau.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"1500","domain_name":"Jambi","domain_url":"https:\/\/jambi.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"1600","domain_name":"Sumatera Selatan","domain_url":"https:\/\/sumsel.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"1700","domain_name":"Bengkulu","domain_url":"https:\/\/bengkulu.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"1800","domain_name":"Lampung","domain_url":"https:\/\/lampung.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"1900","domain_name":"Kep. Bangka Belitung","domain_url":"https:\/\/babel.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"2100","domain_name":"Kep. Riau","domain_url":"https:\/\/kepri.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"3100","domain_name":"Dki Jakarta","domain_url":"https:\/\/jakarta.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"3200","domain_name":"Jawa Barat","domain_url":"https:\/\/jabar.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"3300","domain_name":"Jawa Tengah","domain_url":"https:\/\/jateng.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"3400","domain_name":"Di Yogyakarta","domain_url":"https:\/\/yogyakarta.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"3500","domain_name":"Jawa Timur","domain_url":"https:\/\/jatim.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"3600","domain_name":"Banten","domain_url":"https:\/\/banten.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"5100","domain_name":"Bali","domain_url":"https:\/\/bali.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"5200","domain_name":"Nusa Tenggara Barat","domain_url":"https:\/\/ntb.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"5300","domain_name":"Nusa Tenggara Timur","domain_url":"https:\/\/ntt.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"6100","domain_name":"Kalimantan Barat","domain_url":"https:\/\/kalbar.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"6200","domain_name":"Kalimantan Tengah","domain_url":"https:\/\/kalteng.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"6300","domain_name":"Kalimantan Selatan","domain_url":"https:\/\/kalsel.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"6400","domain_name":"Kalimantan Timur","domain_url":"https:\/\/kaltim.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"6500","domain_name":"Kalimantan Utara","domain_url":"https:\/\/kaltara.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"7100","domain_name":"Sulawesi Utara","domain_url":"https:\/\/sulut.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"7200","domain_name":"Sulawesi Tengah","domain_url":"https:\/\/sulteng.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"7300","domain_name":"Sulawesi Selatan","domain_url":"https:\/\/sulsel.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"7400","domain_name":"Sulawesi Tenggara","domain_url":"https:\/\/sultra.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"7500","domain_name":"Gorontalo","domain_url":"https:\/\/gorontalo.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"7600","domain_name":"Sulawesi Barat","domain_url":"https:\/\/sulbar.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"8100","domain_name":"Maluku","domain_url":"https:\/\/maluku.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"8200","domain_name":"Maluku Utara","domain_url":"https:\/\/malut.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"9100","domain_name":"Papua Barat","domain_url":"https:\/\/papuabarat.bps.go.id"},{"domain_id":"9400","domain_name":"Papua","domain_url":"https:\/\/papua.bps.go.id"}]]}
```

Comment: First: your data array is not right. 2nd: you can do something like in your api respose:  `this.allMusic= musicList.data[1];`

Answer (score 0):

this error cause because your are trying to print json object not an array.
see your response which you get from api. you assign this whole object to             "allMusic" variable. Instead of assign whole object you need to assign array from that object.
just like it.

```
this.allMusic = musicList.data;
```

Hope you it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error it seems, you need to perform iteration on Arrays not object. Look like the attached piece of code you need to the follow the below step to resolve issue.

From the API's response you need to capture the data - it holds the array of objects.

//declare the stored variable
pageList:any  = [];

Once API's response getting you need to assign data objects data into pageList obj, like this way.

this.pageList = response.data;

That's it.